# useEffect render previous value, instead new setState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, setstate

Im trying to set set an IP address into "" and (last queried value).
But its always render same state and render new state after second render.
I know its because of  setState syncronomous behaviour. I have been trying to put timeout and declare indirect value to make it works, but none of these succeed.

```js
**///DECLARED VALUE/////**
  const [ip, setIp] = useState("");
  const [isValid, setIsValid] = useState(true);
  const [buttonActive, setButtonActive] = useState(false);
  const [ipV4Completed, setIpV4Completed] = useState(false);

  const [savedIp, setSavedIp] = useState("");
  const [location, setLocation] = useState("");
  const [isp, setIsp] = useState("");
  const [ipV4, setIpV4] = useState(true);

  const [savedData, setSavedData] = useState("")

  let storageData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("savedData")) || [];

  const onInputChange = (data) => {
    setIp(data.target.value);
    validateInput(data);
  };

  const validateInput = (e) => {
    const ipV4Regex = /^((25[0-5]|(2[0-4]|1\d|[1-9]|)\d)\.?\b){4}$/;
    const ipV6Regex = /^([0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}:){7}[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}$/i;
    let { value } = e.target;

    if (value.match(ipV4Regex)) {
      setIsValid(true);
      setButtonActive(true);
      setIpV4(true);
    } else if (value.match(ipV6Regex)) {
      setIsValid(true);
      setButtonActive(true);
      setIpV4(false);
    } else if (value === "") {
      setIsValid(true);
      setButtonActive(false);
    } else {
      setIsValid(false);
      setButtonActive(false);
    }
  };

**///FUNCTION THAT RETURN SUPPOSED VALUE/////**
  const proceedInput = useCallback(() => {
    console.log('proceedInput called with ip:', ip);
    axios
      .get(
        `https://geo.ipify.org/api/v2/country,city?apiKey=${process.env.REACT_APP_KEY_APIFY}&ipAddress=${ip}`)
      .then((response) => {
        setSavedIp(response.data.ip);
        setLocation(response.data.location);
        setMapLocation(response.data.location);
        setIsp(response.data.isp);

        const ipExist = storageData.some(item => item.ip === response.data.ip);

        if (!ipExist) {
          storageData.push(response.data);
          setSavedData(storageData);
        }
        
        if (ipV4) {
          setIpV4Completed(true);
        } else {
          setIpV4Completed(false);
        };

      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error("Failed to fetch location data:", error);
      });
  }, [ip]);

**///BLOCK WHERE USESTATE NOT DIRECTLY UPDATED/////**
  useEffect(() => {
    if (currentLocation){
      setIp("")
      proceedInput();
    }
  }, [currentLocation])

**///BLOCK WHERE USESTATE NOT DIRECTLY UPDATED/////**
  useEffect(() => {
    if (historyLocation){
      setIp(historyLocation.ip)
      proceedInput();
    }
  }, [historyLocation])

  useEffect(() => {
    if (savedData){
      localStorage.setItem("savedData", JSON.stringify(savedData));
    }
  }, [savedData])
```

Comment: Create an effect that has `ip` as a dependency, instead of calling `proceedInput` (with the old value) directly after `setIp()`

Comment: @Bergi doesnt it will make useeffect render every time ip change. that code always update ip to validate, umm,, the button and input form not connected. after onchange input form value will update ip, button only to proceed to axios

Comment: Don't you want to run the `proceedInput` logic every time the `ip` changes? Not sure what button and input form your are talking about.

Comment: Anyway, then make `ip` a parameter of the function and call it with the right value at the right time.